# Save PostgreSQL logs to a table in different database

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with multiple tables in it and i am maintaining logs of the database on a local drive in files `.csv format` on daily basis, using `postgres.conf`

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'      
logging_collector = on      
log_statement = 'mod'
```

But i don't think it's the best way to do logging. Then i tried to copy the log files in to a table created on a database other than the source database, using `psycopg2`

```
COPY postgres_log 
FROM '/path/to/csv/log.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

i was successful in doing that but again it's not the best way, because each day a new log file is created with new name `(log-%D%M%Y.csv)` and i don't want to do this over and over again

I have also read about `triggers` and `postgres_fdw` extension but i don't know how to write the result of a trigger in to a table other than the source database.

What i want to do is to store the log in a table placed on a database other than the source database with an automated process. Any idea?

Comment: you could do with simple batch / cron job. But, why do you need to store the logs into database?

Comment: so that i can query the logs

Comment: if there is any better way to maintain logs plz suggest one

Comment: why don't you use ``grep`` (linux) / ``findstr``(windows) or similar text processing tools? Is there any constraint?

Comment: my database is too big and i have to handle large logs.. also at the end of the day i will have to report the activities of the database users

Comment: what your operating system, patterns (``log_line_prefix`` and ``log_filename`` in ``postgresql.conf``)?

Comment: `log_line_prefix = %t` and `filename = logfile-%d-%m-%Y.log`. does it matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46239/discussion-between-spike-and-shahzad-bacha).